# Can't find running applications when executing as root on OS X 10.7

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion

I have a privileged helper tool running as root (blessed by SMJobBless) and I'm trying to obtain the process id of Finder. The code below works fine in OS X 10.8, but returns an empty array for finderApps on 10.7.

I've reproduced the issue on two different machines running 10.7 by selecting "root" for the "Debug Process As" option under Schemes on XCode. Strangely, the code works fine if I call it directly using "sudo myTestApp".

Any ideas why I can't get the code to run when launched directly as a daemon process or debugging as root under XCode?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {

    NSArray *finderApps = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.finder"];

    if ([finderApps count] == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"failed to find Finder");

        return -1;
    }

    NSRunningApplication *finderApplication = [finderApps objectAtIndex:0];
    pid_t process_id = [finderApplication processIdentifier];

    NSLog(@"succeeded with procid: %d", process_id);

    return 0;
}
```